# sql query to calculate the difference between two dates of different columns and adjacent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my table.

[image]

I want to populate the break column by calculating the difference between two dates

I want to calculate time between column EndD,EndT and StartD,StartD but of different rows(2nd row).
for e.g-
EndD is '2016-06-01 18:17:48' and start date is '2016-06-01 18:46:05' and break time should be calculated between these two dates

Output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: And please show the table structure (or at least the startD and StarT data types)

Comment: sql server 2008 and table structure if you ask..m using nvarchar(50) for StartD, StartT, EndD,EndT and for Break Time(0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ID, AgentID, StartD, StartT, EndD, EndT,
      DATEDIFF(minute, 
         CAST(t1.EndD + ' ' + t1.EndT AS DATETIME),
         (SELECT CAST(t2.StartD + ' ' + t2.StartT AS DATETIME)
            FROM yourTable t2 
            WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID + 1  AND t1.AgentID = t2.AgentID)) as [break] 
FROM  yourTable t1
```

The Datediff function takes the minutes between an embedded query (which takes the date and time from the next line with same agent) and the date and time of your current row.  Also, be sure to use brackets around your column name "break", since it is a SQL-Server reserved word.

**UPDATE:**

User reported negative values from my answer.  This should be resolved by switching the two date parameters in the `DATEDIFF` function.  I have updated the code (above) to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Dustin.:)But I am getting Breakvalues as negative.

Comment: You should be able to just switch the two date parameters in the DATEDIFF function to fix this (and get positive values).  I just edited my answer to show this

Comment: Yea...Even i was trying to do something like this..Thanks a lot Dustin:)

Answer (score 0):

For tsql that would work

```
update a 
set a.break=datediff(minute,a.endt,b.startt)
from tbl a
inner join tbl b 
on a.startD=b.endD and a.ID=b.ID-1
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008

Comment: Can i use cte for this

Comment: so whats  the issue with using the above query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(minute,'2016-06-01 20:17:48','2016-06-01 20:50:17')
```

Mention that you should change that in order you want and always increase the startT + 1

Comment: It isn't hardcoded my friend. function Datediff returns exactly what you want and that is her job. So if you put as 1st parameter startT (the next) and as 2nd parameter EndT then it will work perfectly